# Avoiding row-wise processing of data.frame in R

Tags: performance, r, dataframe

I was wondering what the best way is to avoid row-wise processing in R, most of row-wise stuff is done in internal C routines. For example: I have a data frame `a`:

```
  chromosome_name start_position end_position strand
1              15       35574797     35575181      1
2              15       35590448     35591641     -1
3              15       35688422     35688645      1
4              13       75402690     75404217      1
5              15       35692892     35693969      1
```

What I want is: based on whether strand is positive or negative, `startOFgene` as `start_position` or `end_position`. One way to avoid `for` loop will be to separate data.frame with +1 strand and -1 strand and perform selection. What can be other way for speed up? The method does not scale-up if one has certain other complicated processing per row.

Comment: have you thought about sorting (check `?order` or `?sort`) your data frame first - it might speed up your search (as for speed up calculations on sorted/ordered matrices)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this is fast enough...

```
transform(a, startOFgene = ifelse(strand == 1, start_position, end_position))


  chromosome_name start_position end_position strand startOFgene
1              15       35574797     35575181      1    35574797
2              15       35590448     35591641     -1    35591641
3              15       35688422     35688645      1    35688422
4              13       75402690     75404217      1    75402690
5              15       35692892     35693969      1    35692892
```

Answer (score 3):

First, since all your columns are integer/numeric, you could use a matrix instead of a data.frame.  Many operations on a matrix are a lot faster than the same operation on a data.frame, even though they're not very different in this case.  Then you can use logical subsetting to create the `startOFgene` column.

```
# Create some large-ish data
M <- do.call(rbind,replicate(1e3,as.matrix(a),simplify=FALSE))
M <- do.call(rbind,replicate(1e3,M,simplify=FALSE))
A <- as.data.frame(M)
# Create startOFgene column in a matrix
m <- function() {
  M <- cbind(M, startOFgene=M[,"start_position"])
  negStrand <- sign(M[,"strand"]) < 0
  M[negStrand,"startOFgene"] <- M[negStrand,"end_position"]
}
# Create startOFgene column in a data.frame
d <- function() {
  A$startOFgene <- A$start_position
  negStrand <- sign(A$strand) < 0
  A$startOFgene[negStrand] <- A$end_position[negStrand]
}
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(m(), d(), replications=10)[,1:6]
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
# 2  d()           10  18.804    1.000    16.501    2.224
# 1  m()           10  19.713    1.048    16.457    3.152
```